# Handle swipe events in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, carousel, swipe

I use a carousel in Sencha Touch 2. How I can handle swipe-left and swipe-right events ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to listen to the [swipe](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-swipe) event on your carousel items along with using  [Ext.event.Event.direction](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.event.Event-property-direction) to handle the direction of your swipe:

```
listeners: {
    initialize: function(c) {
        this.element.on({
            swipe: function(e, node, options) {
                if(e.direction == "left") {
                    alert("Hey! I swipe left");
                } else {
                    alert("Hey! I swipe right");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Working Demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#TLBZB

Comment: But it works sometimes only. Sometimes this swipe function is not rendering in my case...

Comment: It should be `else if (e.direction == "right")` instead of a simple `else {...}`. Otherwise that block will be triggered whenever you swipe to the top, bottom and the right